# using docker compose to run selenium hub and node

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I have this `docker-compose.yml` file from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/selenium-3) that I am using to open selenium hub and node on mac OS . I changed host port to 65299 , as I got error that 4444 is being used.  I have docker desktop 3.5.1 installed

```
 version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "65299:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=65299


  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=65299
```

When I look here -  `http://localhost:65299/grid/console` , I dont see any node registered

Also, on terminal I get this

```
firefox_1       | 20:27:22.110 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to selenium-hub/172.26.0.2:65299
```

Also , in logs it says

```
 Nodes should register to http://172.27.0.2:4444/grid/register/
```

so why is system even trying `172.26.0.2:65299` or may be I am missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HUB_PORT variable of nodes are wrong. 65299 port is the port for accessing hub from outside of docker network. For example you are using this port the access hub from browser.

You need to set 4444 to that variable. That port available to docker network. So nodes can connect hub.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. HUB_PORT is hub container port (4444) that is mapped to 65299